# How to blank a form existing value when loading?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm loading ModelForm to allow users to edit their profile.

I have a sensitive field (like an API key) that I don't want to show the contents of. I only want users to be able to overwrite it, and not read it.

So basically, without using JS, I want to blank the contents of the field.

Here is what I tried, but it still is loading the APK key.

```
self.fields['api_key'].initial = ""
```

Comment: So you need to pass it to the form/render it at all?

Comment: @Johan The value? Nope. But I do need the field so they can still input.

Comment: in your views, after initializing the `form = ModelNameForm()`, try this `form.initial={'api_key':''}`

Comment: @Lemayzeur - on the right path, but that blanks all fields. Not just the 1 that I want blanked.

Comment: try the with your previous way, `form.fields['api_key'].initial = ""`... `form` instead of `self`

Comment: @Lemayzeur I don't have the variable `form` in forms.py. I do have that in my views. So I did what you said in the views, but I had to add the other fields like `'name': instance.name`

Comment: Could you upload your full form.py?